# Need an better method of removing pattern within a string

Tags: c#, string, foreach, arrays

I have a method that to remove the description word base on the string, but I believe that there is more efficient way to do this.

The `iMonster` can be like ***fat* orc rogue**, and I want to remove the ***fat***.

```
    private static string[] _adjectives = { "angry", 
                                            "big", 
                                            "fat", 
                                            "happy",
                                            "large", 
                                            "nasty", 
                                            "fierce", 
                                            "thin",
                                            "small", 
                                            "tall", 
                                            "short" };

    private static string RemoveMonsterAdjective(string iMonster)
    {
        foreach (string adjective in _adjectives)
        {
            if (iMonster.Contains(adjective))
            {
                iMonster = iMonster.Replace(adjective, "").Trim();
                break;
            }
        }
        return iMonster;
    }
```

hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks OK. Is this really a bottleneck for you?

Comment: Your code looks OK. Only one thing: because of the `break` if the imonster is a "big fat nasty orc rogue" you will get "fat nasty orc rogue" as the result.

Comment: @lakedoo As long you manage your `adjectives` array, it seems fine. But you would need a way to elminitae multiple `adjectives` like removing multiple delimiters ;) +1 @nemesv

Comment: thanks, good point about multiple adjectives, I will fix that.

Comment: (relevant only if break is removed) String is immutable so if iMonster is big and _adjectives is large and could result in multiple hits it may help to use StringBuilder or StringBuffer to yield a heavily mutated result. Although it will increase complexity.

Comment: Your code will replace "bigot" with "ot"; this is probably *not* the intended behavior, right?

Comment: @Yoztastic StringBuilder.Replace doesn't appear to be significantly faster than String.Replace: http://ideone.com/qyUgP6 (slower on IDEone, faster locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible short solution is:

```
var words = iMonster.Split(' ');
return string.Join(" ", words.Except(_adjectives));
```

I've done some profiling and compared the various solutions.

With input `fat angry orc happy rogue` and 1000000 iterations:

```
00:00:01.8457067 lakedoo
00:00:01.9772477 Eve
00:00:04.3859120 dasblinkenlight
```

Need to mention that I adapted dasblinkenlight's solution to have all the adjectives in the regex.

EDIT: corrected lakedoo's method by removing the break.

Answer (score 5):

You can do all replacements in a single call using regular expressions, like this:

```
return Regex.Replace(
    iMonster,
    @"\b(angry|big|fat|happy|...)\b",
    ""
).Trim();
```

The idea behind this approach is to construct a *regular expression* that matches any adjective as a single word (so "bigot" would not be matched, while "big" would be matched), and replace that word with an empty string.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/rWcI6W).

Comment: I'd be interested to see a benchmark of this and the looping String.Replace. I would suspect that as the input gets longer and contains more adjectives, the regex is going to overcome its initial overhead and end up faster (less reallocation).

Comment: This solution leaves spaces which were between words

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Fair enough. ;-)

Comment: It seems that the regex, while simpler, is slower even for long strings: http://ideone.com/wWuexS